# Redirect URL to return same content

Tags: proxy

I need to run a test application that loads many images from an external url.

During tests I don't want to access to the external url, so every time it tries to load an image in this way:

```
<img src="www.externaldomain/somewhere/image1.jpg">
<img src="www.externaldomain/from/there/image2.gif">
```

etc.

it will get a "local" image (always the same image) from the same server that is running the test application.

How can I get that in Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u invert the images and inline them, it works even with curl axiom reverted in scramble

Comment: I think it is called the lorem ipsum dolor buttefly effect

Comment: Also, scrambled eggs can be one of the most fantastic, luxurious breakfasts around if you remember a few key things: always use really fresh free-range or organic eggs and good-quality butter, and always keep the eggs moving slowly over a low heat.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well your question, you can use:

```
<img src="file:///path/to/image1.jpg" />
```

For example, if your default location for your web server is `/var/www` and the pictures are in `/var/www/pictures`:

```
<img src="file:///var/www/pictures/image1.jpg" />
```